# Split String into parts in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have just started learning c++ and I was thinking is their any way of splitting strings. Lemme make it more clear.
Suppose user enters the string, date of birth in the following format `dd-mm-yy`. Now I wish to store the date, month and year in 3 different variables. So how do I go about ?? 

**P.S** : I googled a bit and found that this can be accomplished using the `boot::regex`. But still, I was wondering if there was any easier way of doing the same. Being a beginner hampers me. :P 
Anyways, Any help would be appreciated.

**To Brief:**

I want something like this.

```
Enter date: //Accept the date
22-3-17     //Input by user
Date : 22   //Output
Month: 3    //Output
Year : 17   //Output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sscanf function:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string date;
    cin>>date;
    int day, month, year;
    sscanf(date.c_str(), "%d-%d-%d", &day, &month, &year);
    cout << day << ' ' << month << ' ' << year;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods you could do this. For the 'easiest' way I would suggest using std::string::find() methods( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) in combination with std::string::substr() method (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

For the use of regex you do not need boost: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator [] to get the characters of the string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working program that has been compiled, built and successfully ran on an Intel Core 2 Quad Extreme running Windows 7 64-bit using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition that has retrieved the information the OP had asked for in a particular format, parsed the string of information or data appropriately, and displayed the results in the requested or required format.

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

enum ReturnCode {
    RETURN_OK = 0,
    RETURN_ERROR = 1,
}; // ReturnCode

#endif // STDAFX_H
```

**stdafx.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

class Utility {
public:

    static void pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    static std::string  toUpper( const std::string& str );
    static std::string  toLower( const std::string& str );
    static std::string  trim( const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim = " \t\n\r" );

    static unsigned     convertToUnsigned( const std::string& str );
    static int          convertToInt( const std::string& str );
    static float        convertToFloat( const std::string& str );

    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true ); 

private:
    Utility(); // Private - Not A Class Object
    Utility( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented
    Utility& operator=( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented

    template<typename T>
    static bool stringToValue( const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues );

    template<typename T>
    static T getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder );

}; // Utility

#include "Utility.inl"

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

**Utility.inl**

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// stringToValue()
template<typename T>
static bool Utility::stringToValue(const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues) {
    int numCommas = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ',');
    if (numCommas != uNumValues - 1) {
        return false;
    }

    std::size_t remainder;
    pValue[0] = getValue<T>(str, remainder);

    if (uNumValues == 1) {
        if (str.size() != remainder) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::size_t offset = remainder;
        if (str.at(offset) != ',') {
            return false;
        }

        unsigned uLastIdx = uNumValues - 1;
        for (unsigned u = 1; u < uNumValues; ++u) {
            pValue[u] = getValue<T>(str.substr(++offset), remainder);
            offset += remainder;
            if ((u < uLastIdx && str.at(offset) != ',') ||
                (u == uLastIdx && offset != str.size()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
} // stringToValue
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// pressAnyKeyToQuit()
void Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit() {
    std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
} // pressAnyKeyToQuit

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toUpper()
std::string Utility::toUpper(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper);
return result;
} // toUpper


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toLower()
std::string Utility::toLower(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower);
    return result;
} // toLower

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// trim()
// Removes Elements To Trim From Left And Right Side Of The str
std::string Utility::trim(const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim) {
    std::basic_string<char>::size_type firstIndex = str.find_first_not_of(elementsToTrim);
    if (firstIndex == std::string::npos) {
        return std::string(); // Nothing Left
    }

    std::basic_string<char>::size_type lastIndex = str.find_last_not_of(elementsToTrim);
    return str.substr(firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1);
} // trim

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
float Utility::getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
    return std::stof(str, &remainder);
} // getValue <float>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
int Utility::getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
    return std::stoi(str, &remainder);
} // getValue <int>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
unsigned Utility::getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
    return std::stoul(str, &remainder);
} // getValue <unsigned>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToUnsigned()
unsigned Utility::convertToUnsigned(const std::string& str) {
    unsigned u = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &u, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to unsigned";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return u;
} // convertToUnsigned

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToInt()
int Utility::convertToInt(const std::string& str) {
    int i = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &i, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to int";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return i;
} // convertToInt

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToFloat()
float Utility::convertToFloat(const std::string& str) {
    float f = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &f, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to float";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return f;
} // convertToFloat

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// splitString()
std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;

} // splitString
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

int main () {
    std::string date;
    std::cout << "Enter Date in DD-MM-YY Format.\n" << std::endl;

    std::getline( std::cin, date );

    std::vector<std::string> vResults = Utility::splitString( date, "-" );

    std::cout << "\nDate : " << vResults[0] << std::endl
              << "Month: " << vResults[1] << std::endl
              << "Year : " << vResults[2] << std::endl << std::endl;    

    Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();   
    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: This utility class might seem like a little too much at first, however it is a very handy class to encapsulate many string manipulation functions that one would use over and over again. This class is not an "object" class meaning you can not create an instance of a Utility object as its constructor is private. However, all methods are static so the use of it is simple. Just include the header where needed and use the scope resolution operator. Also if you have any predefined constant strings you can place them here statically in this class's public section to keep things tidy.